# How to manipulate a packet and write the packet to a pcap file?

Tags: java, pcap, libpcap, jnetpcap

I used to code with `Scapy` in python. Now I'm going to manipulate packets in a `pcap` file using java. For example I need to read the `pcap` file and then alter one packet's source ip.

Actually, I've altered one field using `jNetStream` library, but I don't know how to write the modified packet to `pcap` file

**EDIT:**

I've just provided some codes which belong to packet modification.

```
Decoder decoder = new Decoder("fileName.pcap");
while ((packet = decoder.nextPacket()) != null) {
    new_saddr = InetAddress.getByName("1.1.1.1").getAddress();
    saddr.setAddress(new_saddr);
```

As it could be seen, the new source Ip Address has been set. Now I want to write the whole packets to a new `pcap` file but I don't know how to do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be useful to provide your code

Comment: @ChrisJ Thanks for your comment. I've done it.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for jnetpcap? It describes how to dump captured packages to a file: http://jnetpcap.com/?q=node/69

Comment: @BenDamer Yes I already checked it out. If I use dump method, then I won't be able to manipulate packets. I jest could dump it into another pcap file.

Comment: Why not? PcapDumper.dump has the ability to dump individual packets to a Pcap file. Just load the original file, manipulate each packet, and dump each to a target file.

Comment: @BenDamer That's great. But I had problem with manipulating the packet. For example there was no method to set ip address. I'd be thankful if you help me out with an example. Thanks indeed